# Set an image as background for all screen resolutions

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, storyboard

I'm in trouble with the design part of my app and I hope someone will be able to help me. Here is the description of my problem:

I would like to put an image in background of all views of my app adapting all screen resolutions. My designer has given to me these background images in different sizes (for all devices, iPhone and iPad). I'm not using size classes because it's an old project. I have two storyboards: one for iPad devices and another one for iPhone devices. I created an `UIImageView`, put it on my view in storyboard and added the good constraints (stick to all sides)

I tried two methods to achieve my goal:

1. Using the slicing method but the problem is I have some logos on my
   image and it become difficult to slice.
2. Using the `Mode` of the image in storyboard like `Aspect fill`, `Aspect fit`, `Scale to fill` and so on. The problem with this method is that the background seems to be good for one device, but distorted for all other devices.

I searched all over the web to find something but without success. Is someone already had this issue and found a solution ?

Thanks a lot in advance !

Comment: why cant you specify each image according to size in code?

Comment: Thanks for your response Sujith ! I thought about this solution but I didn't try it. Actually, I wonder if it's possible to deal with images in storyboard. Don't you think it is ?

Comment: have you tried using the [asset catalogue](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/AddingImages.html)?

Comment: Hi Fonix and thanks for your response ! Sure I did. But in asset catalog, I can't specify image for each device resolution, just for 1x, 2x and 3x.

Comment: iphone devices 5,5s,6,6 plus ,6s  ,6s plus are in same screen  size ratio.. so you can set one image in your iphone story board and it will scale properly to all of these devices . But in iphone 4 the screen size ratio is different , so you will have add it in code only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is in viewDidLoad determine the screen size and set a different image; you might want to do the same if your screen is being rotated.

Comment: Thanks for your response gnasher729 ! No way to do that in a storyboard way ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `Mode` property of `UIView`,

If you `Aspect fill` then your image will be set and cropped as per size, but on use of `Aspect fill` you need to use `clipToBound` to `YES` as well,

If you use `Aspect fit` then image will be display as its Aspect Ratio.

But for background the `Aspect fill` will be the best with `clipToBound` to `YES`

Comment: Thanks for your response ! I tried to set my `UIImageView` Mode to `Aspect fill` and set `clipToBound` to `YES`. According to the size of the image in my asset catalog, it's working on certain device resolutions but when I switch on another resolution, the image doesn't cover whole the screen, I get blank spaces on both sides.

Comment: Then you need to set the maximum size of the image.

Comment: I did, the image size I'm using is 1242x2208 set on 2x box in image set of the asset catalog. I also tried to put 640x960 in 1x, 750x1334 in 2x and 1242x2208 in 3x.

Comment: just put 1242x2208 as @1x and try.

Comment: Try to check your leading and trailing constraints for the imageView. If they are relative to the margins on some devices the image will be smaller than the screen size.

Comment: They are relative to superview so I think it's ok this way. I tried to put 1242x2208 as @1x but the problem is still the same. The image goes out of the screen on iPhone 4S (ok for the rest).

Comment: Yes, the iPhone 4s takes the @2x image as the 5/5s because the screen has the same Retina resolution. To solve this you should check the screen size and use another assets name for the 4s image.

Comment: Yes, exactly we need to set different image for iPhone 4, because the aspect ration of iPhone 5, iPhone 6,  and iPhone 6P is same, but for iPhone 4 its different. So you need to put a condition and set the different image for iPhone 4s.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to set the same background image for every viewcontroller you can try this in your appdelegate
 `[self.window setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"default"]]];` and set background color of your viewcontroller to clearColor,thats it. I have done the same thing in one of my application. Feel free to ask further suggestions...

Comment: Thanks for your response ! I tried your solution but I get the same problem with the iPhone 4 (image cropped). But thanks anyway !

Comment: Autolayout is not working on iPhone4 but it is working from iPhone4s. So you can check whether your iPhone is iPhone4 or not. If it's iPhone4 then set bonds property to your UIImageView. It will work.